# Need help understanding a line in tsocks FAQ

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, configuration, proxy

Over [here](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/faq.php#local) they explain an error I am getting running tsocks:

> I keep getting an error like "SOCKS server is not on a local subnet!",
>   what's going on?
>
> By definition SOCKS servers in the tsocks configuration file must be
>   on networks specified by a "local" subnet statement. Remember that a
>   'local' subnet doesn't describe a subnet that the machine is directly
>   attached to but rather networks that the machine can reach without the
>   aid of any SOCKS server (thus such networks are "local" networks).
>
> When you think about it, if a SOCKS server were on a network that
>   wasn't local then you would need a SOCKS server in order to be able to
>   reach the SOCKS server (which can actually occur in some strange
>   networks but tsocks doesn't yet support that sort of network).
>
> To fix your problem just define the network your SOCKS server is on in
>   a local subnet statement.

The error is the same thing they have mentioned - `... is not on a local subnet!failed: Connection refused.`

Can you please explain what is meant by:

> To fix your problem just define the network your SOCKS server is on in
>   a local subnet statement.

How can I "define" the network my SOCKS server is on in my local subnet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to define the subnet which the server you are trying to connect to lives in as a local subnet in the tsocks.conf file.

From the documentation here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/tsocks.conf

> The basic structure of all lines in the configuration file is:
>
> <directive> = <parameters>
>
> ...
>
> local
>
> An IP/Subnet pair specifying a network which may be accessed
>   directly without proxying through a SOCKS server (e.g "local =
>   10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0"). Obviously all SOCKS server IP addresses must be in networks specified as local, otherwise tsocks would need a SOCKS
>   server to reach SOCKS servers.

So if you are trying to connect to say 10.10.10.10 then you need a line like one of the below (depending on how wide you want to define your subnet):

```
local=10.10.10.10/255.255.255.255
local=10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0
local=10.10.0.0/255.255.0.0
local=10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
```

Obviously these are just a few of the possible 32 subnet masks you can use :))